# Link angular-translate locale string to translation file?

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, angular-translate

*WebStorm* is able to go to specific declarations of angular components by *CTRL + Click*. For example with mdVirtualRepeatContainer:

[image]

It would be nice, if there is a way to jump this way to the declaration of *angular-translate* locales like:

```
{{ 'myApp.title' | translate }}
```

*CTRL + Click* on `myApp.title` and go to:

```
//assets/locales/myApp/en.json
{
  "myApp": {
    "title": "this is the title, I want to go to"
  }
}
```

**My question**

Is there a way to tell *WebStorm* that everything piped to *translate* can potentially be found under `assets/locales/`?

Comment: I don't think that is built in into Webstorm, but that could be a good idea for a plugin !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in WebStorm; related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28258.
It's unlikely that it will ever be included, but it is indeed a good idea for custom plugin